# How to start-up web app in full-screen mode via Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've tried '--kiosk', '--start-maximized'; but all not work, any solution yet?

Further, the web app is to be displayed onto the extended desktop across multiple monitors in full-screen mode, how can I achieve this?

I'm currently using Chrome 16.0.912.63

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, web-app mode should be the closest approach: chrome.exe --app=""